# Object falling with air resistance using Runge-Kutta

Tags: ode, computational-physics, runge-kutta

I am not very familiar with differential equations, nor physics in general.  I am trying to program an object falling with air resistance with the use of a numerical algorithm called Runge-Kutta. The object is going to fall from the same position every-time $x=0$, with the same start speed $v=0$ every time.

I think I then need to work with the equation: $ma=F_d-mg$, where $F_d$ is the drag and it's variables are $\frac {1}{2} pdAv^2$.

$ma=F_d-mg  \rightarrow ma = \frac {1}{2} pdAv^2-mg$, where $A$ is the area, a constant.

If I solve for $a$, the acceleration I get the equation:

$a = \frac {\frac 12pdav^2}{m}-g$

This is the differential equation:

$y'' = \frac {\frac 12pda(y')^2}{m}-g$

Because I am going to solve for this using the Runge-Kutta numerical method I am going to have to rewrite this into two first order differentials equations. ¨

I thus start by saying:

$ \frac{dx}{dt} = v $

and then

$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac {\frac 12pda(v)^2}{m}-g$

Now that I have my two first order differential equations I should be fine plugging them into the Runge-Kutta method, to obtain the velocity and the position.

Here is a picture of what I have programmed. Using the initial values:

- $p = 0.5$
- $d = 1.275$
- $a = 0.003184$
- $m = 0.14529$
- $g = 9.81$

  ```
  using UnityEngine;
  using System.Collections;

  public class ODESOLVER1 : MonoBehaviour {}

  float t_n = 0; 
  float y_n = 0;
  float h = 0.1;
  float x_n = 0;
  float p = 0.5;
  float d = 1.275;
  float a = 0.003184;
  float m = 0.14529; 
  float g = 9.81; 

  void Start () {
      for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
      {
          RungaKrutta4(t_n, y_n, x_n, h);
          Debug.Log("t_n=" + t_n + "y_n=" + y_n + "x_n=" + x_n);
      };
  }

  void Update () {}


  private void repeatKrutta() {}

  private void RungaKrutta4(float t_n, float y_n, float x_n, float h) {

      float k0 = h * function1(t_n, y_n, x_n);
      float l0 = h*function2(t_n, y_n, x_n);
      float k1 = h * function1(t_n + (h / 2), y_n + (k0 / 2), x_n + (l0 / 2));
      float l1 = h * function2(t_n + (h / 2), y_n + (k0 / 2), x_n + (l0 / 2));
      float k2 = h * function1(t_n + (h / 2), y_n + (k1 / 2), x_n + (l1 / 2));
      float l2 = h*function2(t_n + (h/2), y_n + (k1/2), x_n + (l1/2));
      float k3 = h * function1(t_n + (h / 2), y_n + (k2 / 2), x_n + (l2 / 2));
      float l3 = h*function2(t_n + (h/2), y_n + (k2/2), x_n + (l2/2));

     this.t_n = t_n + h; 
     this.y_n = y_n + ((h / 6) * (k0 + (2 * k1) + (2 * k2) + k3));
     this.x_n = x_n + ((h / 6) * (l0 + (2 * l1) + (2 * l2) + l3));
  }

  private float function1(float t, float y, float x) {
      return (((0.5f * p * d * a * y * y)/m) - g);
  }


  private float function2(float t, float y, float x) {
      return (y);
  }

  private void calculateDecimals(float value) {
      string s = System.Convert.ToString(value); 
  }
  ```

My $y_{n+1}$ almost comes out correctly except for the fact that it becomes a much smaller value. If the speed should have been $0.0981$ with a timestep $h = 0.010$, it comes out as $0.000981.$  in the first iteration for example.

My $x_{n+1}$ does not come correctly out at all. The first, second and third values should be as follows: $-0.00049, -0.00196, -0.0441 $ with a timestep of $h=0.010.$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's either a [check-my-work question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) or a question about debugging code, which are both off-topic.

Comment: But isn't there a possibility that you could at least answer the physics part of the problem?

Comment: as a hint: check how the deviation between what you get and what you should get changes with $h$ (or more bluntly: how many powers of h should you have in a first order integration)

Comment: 1) There is only one "r" in Runge-Kutta. 2) I suspect that h (which you have not shown) has a value of .01, which explains the small velocity change. 3) This in turn will produce very small velocity increments, but you have not indicated what is wrong with this, other than "does not come correctly out at all", so no one can help you there.

Comment: You can add the code leaving  four spaces before, instead of using an image for that. Also, be sure to include a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can run your code if wanted.

Comment: I will. The thing is, I am not sure if the code is wrong, or the formula is wrong or something else is wrong. The physics guys didn't say anything about the formula though before they moved it, so I bet that is probably correct.  My code is not long though, it's exactly as written but with some variables.

Comment: Well, I see that you have two different $a$ variables in your equation, it would be better to replace one of them for another, like $A$. Also, I don't understand what are the $f$s in the initial values.

Comment: the f's were just to show they were a float number. I have removed them.

Comment: What is the objective of this exercise? Are you trying to learn some basic physics, Java programming, this UnityEngine software package, or how the Runge-Kutta algorithm works? Your implementation of Runge-Kutta may be correct but looks pretty convoluted to me. Most scientists/engineers don't try to implement their own ODE solver but instead use one of the many freely-available solvers.

Comment: It's about simulation and physics, I therefore have to understand how the algorithm works among others, and how to apply them to the different physics problems involved in a game/simulation, It's both physics, and the algorithm really.

Comment: Without looking at it any closer, the factor of `h/6` in assignments `this.y_n, this.x_n` looks intuitively wrong to me, makes adjustments scale as $h^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not going to compile everything to see if this is your only mistake (you can [check here for an RK4 implementation](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DifferentialEquations.jl/blob/master/src/ode/ode_integrators.jl#L530)). However, one clear error is that the fourth step has a stepsize `h` and not `h/2`. So you should have

```
float k3 = h * function1(t_n + h , y_n + k2, x_n + l2);
float l3 = h*function2(t_n + h, y_n + k2, x_n + l2);
```

Just for reference, the method with all halves (like you had) is only $\mathcal{O}(h^2)$, but it's more stable than RK4.

```
(2 * k1) + (2 * k2)
```

is unnecessary,

```
2 * (k1 * k2)
```

gets rid of an operation. Also, the update step should be

```
this.y_n = y_n + ((1 / 6) * (k0 + (2 * k1) + (2 * k2) + k3));
this.x_n = x_n + ((1 / 6) * (l0 + (2 * l1) + (2 * l2) + l3));
```

i.e. get rid of the $h$'s there. Most people don't know this, but the RK methods actually respect units / dimensional analysis. Check the dimensions (where $f$ is a rate): `function1(t_n, y_n, x_n)` is a rate, so `h * function1(t_n, y_n, x_n)` has the same dimensions as `y_n`. Since you multiplied the `h` already, your `k`'s aren't rates, but actually the same units as the `y_n` and `x_n` and so the last step is just a linear combination.

There's no reason to `t_n + (h / 2)` so many times. Save that value to cut down on operations. `RungaKrutta4` should be `RungaKutta4`

These are all of the mistakes I could find while quickly skimming over your RK4, and RK4 is one of the simplest methods (you have no adaptive timestepping, stabilization, interpolation, or optimizations like within-method multithreading, explicit fused-multiply added, etc.). This is one reason why, for most people, I would recommend that they use tried and tested ODE solver packages.

Comment: So I removed the h, fixed k3 and l3, and I figured out that 1/6 also caused me some troubled so I changed it into a floating point number instead and now it works as it should. Thanks.